# How to continue execution of task does not depend on failed dependsOn task

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I created a custom task which is throwing the `StopExecutionException`. However the task is not failed and gradle continues to execute next task which dependsOn failed task.

**Custom Task:**

```
class EMTest extends DefaultTask { {
    @TaskAction
    public void exec() {
        def outFile = new File(System.env.T_WORK + '/' + project.lrgName + '-' + name + '-gradle.out')
        def errFile = new File(System.env.T_WORK + '/' + project.lrgName + '-' + name + '-gradle.err')
        def execResult = this.executeTestNgTests(project.configurations.lrgConfig, testngXml, outputDir, outFile, errFile)
        try {
            execResult.assertNormalExitValue()
            if (errFile.length()) {

                println "Block ${name} failed. Throwing exception 2"
                throw new StopExecutionException("Block ${name} failed.")
            }
        } catch (ExecException e) {
            println "Block ${name} failed. Throwing exception"
            throw new StopExecutionException("Block ${name} failed.")
        }
    }
    protected ExecResult executeTestNgTests(def cp, testngXml, outputDir, outFile, errFile) {
        log.info("Classpath is " +  cp)
        def execResult = project.javaexec {
            ignoreExitValue true
            main "org.testng.TestNG"
            classpath cp
            args testngXml, "-d", outputDir

            standardOutput new FileOutputStream(outFile)
            errorOutput new FileOutputStream(errFile)
        }
        return execResult
    }
}
```

build.gradle

```
task sampleA(type: EMTest)

task sampleB (type: EMTest, dependsOn: [sampleA])
```

Now when I execute `build.gradle`, both `sampleA` and `sampleB` are run. While I expect `sampleA` to fail and should not run `sampleB`

What am I missing ?

Comment: Provide full example.

Answer (score 2):

`StopExecutionException` stops execution of the current task, and continues with the next one (see Javadoc). To stop the build, throw any other exception (`GradleException` is a common choice).

Comment: Thanks Peter, `GradleException` works to stop the build. My requirement is not to stop the build, but to stop the dependent tasks from being executed if the dependsOn task fails. For example, if there are 3 tasks, taskA, taskB and taskC. taskA is independent. taskC depends on taskB. Then here if there is some failure in taskB, taskC should not execute, but taskA should continue to run. Any solution available for this ?

Comment: Please rephrase your question accordingly. The (only) way to achieve this is with `--continue`.